# How can I change the default install path by using zypper in suse 11.2?

Tags: linux, suse, zypper

There is no useful argument for my question in this command `zypper -h` . 
Can anyone help me or tell me how to install yum instead of zypper in suse 11.2 ?

```
  Usage:
    zypper [--global-options] <command> [--command-options] [arguments]

  Global Options:
    --help, -h      Help.
    --version, -V       Output the version number.
    --promptids     Output a list of zypper's user prompts.
    --config, -c <file> Use specified config file instead of the default.
    --quiet, -q     Suppress normal output, print only error
                messages.
    --verbose, -v       Increase verbosity.
    --no-abbrev, -A     Do not abbreviate text in tables.
    --table-style, -s   Table style (integer).
    --rug-compatible, -r    Turn on rug compatibility.
    --non-interactive, -n   Do not ask anything, use default answers
                automatically.
    --non-interactive-include-reboot-patches
                Do not treat patches as interactive, which have
                the rebootSuggested-flag set.
    --xmlout, -x        Switch to XML output.

    --reposd-dir, -D <dir>  Use alternative repository definition file
                directory.
    --cache-dir, -C <dir>   Use alternative directory for all caches.
    --raw-cache-dir <dir>   Use alternative raw meta-data cache directory.
    --solv-cache-dir <dir>  Use alternative solv file cache directory.
    --pkg-cache-dir <dir>   Use alternative package cache directory.

     Repository Options:
    --no-gpg-checks     Ignore GPG check failures and continue.
    --gpg-auto-import-keys  Automatically trust and import new repository
                signing keys.
    --plus-repo, -p <URI>   Use an additional repository.
    --disable-repositories  Do not read meta-data from repositories.
    --no-refresh        Do not refresh the repositories.
    --no-cd         Ignore CD/DVD repositories.
    --no-remote     Ignore remote repositories.

     Target Options:
    --root, -R <dir>    Operate on a different root directory.
    --disable-system-resolvables
                Do not read installed packages.



     Repository Management:
    repos, lr       List all defined repositories.
    addrepo, ar     Add a new repository.
    removerepo, rr      Remove specified repository.
    renamerepo, nr      Rename specified repository.
    modifyrepo, mr      Modify specified repository.
    refresh, ref        Refresh all repositories.
    clean           Clean local caches.

     Service Management:
    services, ls        List all defined services.
    addservice, as      Add a new service.
    modifyservice, ms   Modify specified service.
    removeservice, rs   Remove specified service.
    refresh-services, refs  Refresh all services.

     Software Management:
    install, in     Install packages.
    remove, rm      Remove packages.
    verify, ve      Verify integrity of package dependencies.
    source-install, si  Install source packages and their build
                dependencies.
    install-new-recommends, inr
                Install newly added packages recommended
                by installed packages.

     Update Management:
    update, up      Update installed packages with newer versions.
    list-updates, lu    List available updates.
    patch           Install needed patches.
    list-patches, lp    List needed patches.
    dist-upgrade, dup   Perform a distribution upgrade.
    patch-check, pchk   Check for patches.

     Querying:
    search, se      Search for packages matching a pattern.
    info, if        Show full information for specified packages.
    patch-info      Show full information for specified patches.
    pattern-info        Show full information for specified patterns.
    product-info        Show full information for specified products.
    patches, pch        List all available patches.
    packages, pa        List all available packages.
    patterns, pt        List all available patterns.
    products, pd        List all available products.
    what-provides, wp   List packages providing specified capability.

     Package Locks:
    addlock, al     Add a package lock.
    removelock, rl      Remove a package lock.
    locks, ll       List current package locks.
    cleanlocks, cl      Remove unused locks.

     Other Commands:
    versioncmp, vcmp    Compare two version strings.
    targetos, tos       Print the target operating system ID string.
    licenses        Print report about licenses and EULAs of
                installed packages.
```

Comment: What do you get for `zypper install yum`?

Comment: The package manager for SUSE (OpenSUSE and SLES) family of GNU/Linux distributions is zypper and it is not easily replaceable by yum which is the package manager of choice for Red Hat, CentOS and Fedora. What you should be doing is to think why would you need to replace zypper and then, if that indeed is the case, you might want to post your question to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) which would suit your question better than Stack Overflow (as your question has nothing to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: No,It doesn't work.Maybe i don't have the correct repo that has yum.

Comment: OK,I know how to do it! I can use `zypper -R <dir>` to change the root path.And then the software would be installed in a directory that I want

Comment: zypper -R doesn't change the root path:
`-R, --no-force-resolution   Do not force the solver to find a solution, let it ask.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **zypper install** to install the software to the default location.

Then use 
**rpm --relocate oldpath=newpath** to move to the desired newpath.

Comment: Thanks, Although a long time has passed .